# Mac App Store Update

Tags: mac-appstore

Today I was checking if there are any updates on Mac App Store and look what type of message came out. What do I need to do ?[image]

Comment: Are you in your regular network?

Answer (score 1):

Check your internet connection. This could happen for example if you're connecting through a corporate network or wireless hot spot that proxies all traffic through a central server.

If you are using your normal internet connection, where OS X Update usually works, and this is the first time you get this error message, it could be a cause of concern.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a problem on Apples side.

Just read [this article](http://www.macrumors.com/2014/05/25/apple-software-update-invalid/) on MacRumors.